Why Swiper is rendering over the page?
swiperJS
Why Swiper is rendering over the page? Like in this screenshot.
Also stackoverflow argues that there are too much code in the question, so I gotta fill this up with something
HTML:
            <div class="green-tariff__slider swiper-container">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide green-tariff__slide">
                  <img src="/img/green-tariff/01.jpg" alt="house">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide green-tariff__slide">
                  <img src="/img/green-tariff/01.jpg" alt="house">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide green-tariff__slide">
                  <img src="/img/green-tariff/01.jpg" alt="house">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

CSS:
.green-tariff {
    padding: 150px 0px 0px 0px;

    &__title {
        margin: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
    }

    &__wrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    &__block {
        max-width: 600px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;

        &-title {
            margin: 0px 0px 17px 0px;
        }
    }

    &__tabs {
        max-width: 510px;
        min-width: 0;
    }
}

I've tried to initialize SwiperJS again, checked html structured. Maybe I'm just dumb.

Your Q is not clear
